# Calculate variance of variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came across this interesting question and I need some assistance.

We have a random variable that is selected from a distribution N(1,4) with probability 0.3 and another distribution N(2,5) with probability 0.7. What is the variance of X?

I thought of using the combination rule of distributions with a factor of the probabilities but I'm not sure.

What should I do?

Comment: Show us what you calculated if you were to go along with your proposed method, and perhaps we can provide more help.

Comment: Lookup: the Law of Total Variance.

Comment: You can see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/what-is-the-variance-of-the-weighted-mixture-of-two-gaussians